# Layout is moving up when keyboard appears

Tags: java, android

Here is my xml file.......I am trying to build a layout where if the keyboard appears then the layout can be scrolled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:background="@drawable/squareshape"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priority"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/setpriority"
            android:textColor="@color/actionbarcolor"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width=".1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".01"
            android:background="@android:color/black"></View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:alpha=".5"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/date"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="0"
            android:text="@string/setdate"
            android:textColor="@color/actionbarcolor"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        />

        <View
            android:layout_width=".1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".01"
            android:background="@android:color/black"></View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:alpha=".5"
            android:layout_weight=".5"

            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/time"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="0"
            android:text="@string/settime"
            android:textColor="@color/actionbarcolor"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        />

        <View
            android:layout_width=".1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".01"
            android:background="@android:color/black"></View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:alpha=".5"

            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/location"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="0"
            android:text="@string/setlocation"
            android:textColor="@color/actionbarcolor"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1.07" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/squareshape">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newnote_edittext_note"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/squareshape"

            android:gravity="top" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"

            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_addphoto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/picturebuttonnor" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1_video"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/videobuttonnor" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="newnote_imageview_audio"
            android:src="@drawable/audiobuttonnor" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

   </ScrollView>
```

When the keyboard appears,the layout is moving up.So the entire layout isn't scrolling.How to stop this?Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Try define the following attribute in  of AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Specifying "`adjustResize`" is important if your UI includes controls that the user might need to access immediately after or while performing text input.Fore more info check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)